# How to draw line point by point in Swift

Tags: swift, multithreading, mapkit

I realised that I'm misusing the data retrived from the server in my tracker app. So I have this:

```
 @objc private func updateOnlineTrackWithNewData() {

    print("Tick")

    if let track = track {

        guard track.status == 1 else { return } // is track online?

        serverManager.tracks.updateOnlineTrack(for: track, success: { (trackNewPoints) in 
       //receive new data

            guard trackNewPoints.count > 1 else { return }

            for point in trackNewPoints {

                self.track?.points?.append(point)

                self.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(self.updateOnlineTrackOnMap), with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)

            }

        }) { (error) in

            print(error ?? "Error updating online track")

           }
    }
}
```

Where trackNewPoints is basically an array of points that I'm appending to the main "track" and updateOnlineTrackOnMap is just printing it out. updateOnlineTrackWithNewData() function is triggered by timer, everything works correctly. But I want to draw line point by point to simulate realtime movement. How can I achieve that? performSelector doesn't seem to work.

Every 10 seconds I have 10 new points or so if that helps.

Comment: can you lower update interval?

Comment: There will be just emtpy JSON responses @tereks

Comment: all right, i see you can afford to draw points in "past", so why don't you create timer with 1 second interval and draw 1 point from newPoints every timer tick?

Comment: I don't know how to tell the machine to wait for a second in that for in loop. Tried timer, they are driving each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one way to do it. Create separate class Drawer

```
protocol Drawable { // add to your controller 
    func appendPoint(_ point: AnyObject)
    func updateOnlineTrackOnMap()
}

class Drawer {

    private var timer: Timer? = nil
    private var points: [AnyObject] = []

    func drawPoints(_ points: [AnyObject],
                    controller: Drawable) {
        self.points = points
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
            guard let point = self?.points.first else {
                timer.invalidate()
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
                controller.appendPoint(point)
                controller.updateOnlineTrackOnMap()
                self?.points.remove(at: 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works like magic. Thank you!! But could you please guide me through this DispatchQueue.global part? What should I read about it? I'm not sure if I understand this piece of code

Comment: I supposed that updateOnlineTrackOnMap invokes drawRect method and thus I put update code in async block with highest priority to lower burden of main thread. Read multithreading with GCD, mainly what should be done in main tread and what - not